# glLoadIdentity and glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix, why not just use the former?

Tags: opengl, graphics

When applying transformations to objects we use glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix. But why don't we use glLoadIdentity only instead?

Thus

```
    glPushMatrix()
    ..apply tranformations
    ...draw object
    glPopMatrix()
    glPushMatrix()
    ..apply tranformations
    ...draw object
    glPopMatrix()
```

This is how its supposed to be done right?

can become

```
    glLoadIdentity()
    ..apply tranformations
    ...draw object
    glLoadIdentity()
    ..apply tranformations
    ...draw object
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you wouldn't be able to do this:

```
glPushMatrix()
..apply tranformations
glPushMatrix()
..apply ADDITIONAL transformations
..draw object with combined transforms
glPopMatrix()
...draw object without the additional transforms.
glPopMatrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good explanation on: https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/595000

> They don't have the same effect.
>
> glLoadIdentity replaces the current matrix with the identity matrix.
>
> glPushMatrix pushes the current matrix onto a stack. You can then pull
> the top matrix off the stack and make it the current one later using
> glPopMatrix.
>
> **Those are only the same if**:
>
> - your camera is always fixed at (0, 0, 0) looking along z
> - all of your models are single, rigid shapes
> - you loaded your matrix stack with the identity in the first place
>
> Or if you're doing lots of unnecessary arithmetic yourself on the CPU,
> making your code more complicated and your application less speedy.